# Real Time Facebook and Twitter Update Tutorials

Tags: caching, facebook-graph-api, callback, twitter, real-time-updates

I want to be able to get real time updates from facebook and twitter (for a predefined user who has registered to show their content on a site, not the user who is browsing the site). I have read through the docs but there is a wealth of information available and a lot of the concepts are new to me. Whilst I'm not averse to learning and would quite like to, I have no idea where to start.

For instance, I have no idea how to set up a callback, or to cache requests etc.

Where are some good tutorials on how to do this?

n.b. I am slowly wading through their online docs...

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial at http://www.codedestination.com/1/post/2013/05/-facebook-real-time-updates-api-tutorial-part-i.html. It explains how to subscribe and how to set up a callback.

I hope it helps.